# Getting NullPointer Exception while using android.R.id.title

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I am trying to get textview like `android.r.id.title` to show my tab name.
But it's throwing NullPointerException on 2.2 but it's working fine on `>=4.x`.

Here is my code for reference.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {     
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height /= 2;
            Log.i("TESTING WIDTH OF TABS ", ""
                    + mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getWidth());
            View tabView = getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);

            View v = (View) tabView.getParent();
            tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            Typeface faceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/eau_sans_bold.otf");
            tv.setTypeface(faceBold);
            tv.setTextSize(12);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
            tv.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

And here my logcat.

```
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com./com..ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com..ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:471)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-06 19:22:38.764: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

I don't understand why i am getting this exception.
Please give me any hint or reference.

Comment: which line is 471? (this will immediately tell you what is null)

Comment: Post your code for onCreate()...

Comment: @njzk2 Typeface faceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "fonts/eau_sans_bold.otf");

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil : are you sure? there is no reference called on this line, this seems quite unlikely that this line throws an NPE.

Comment: i remove this line now exception showing on View v = (View) tabView.getParent();

Comment: actually error is related to tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

Comment: is this problem of 2.2 or 2.3... because it's working on 4.2 and 4.3... if yes then is there any alternative..

Comment: Seems like `tabView.getParent()` returned `null`. Check it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code logic and use the [`TabHost.TabSpec.setIndicator(View view`)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29) method to change the tab names. You can initiate your `TextView` programmaticaly (avoiding `findViewById`) and set it as parameter to this method. This way, your code is more safe to errors like the one you describe since you are independent from the view hierarchy changes in different android versions.